# How can i overwrite a single line in a text file?

Tags: java

I am wondering how can i overwrite one line of code in my textfile, i am creating highscores and i want to know how to overwrite the line of code that changes the top difficulty rating for all the scores.  Right now i am using bufferedWriter.write(""+difficultyRating+""); but it does not overwrite the previous score.

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm MM/dd/yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());//gets time to say when the score was made
FileWriter fileWriter;
double difficultyRating;
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;

public void printHighScores(String p1Name, long elapsedTime, int boardWidth, int boardLength, int mines, boolean avoidDoublePrint, File highScores){


            //writes to a file their score
            try{
                //stops error where it would print multiple times on file
                if(avoidDoublePrint){
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(highScores, true);//creates a writer to write in file highScores
                    bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);//also makes it so to write in
                double bw=(double) boardWidth;
                double bl=(double) boardLength;
                double ms=(double) mines;
                difficultyRating = ms/(bl*bw)*100;//finds the difficulty rating on a scale of 1-10 based on mines per square
                DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");//formats to 2 decimals
                    bufferedWriter.write(""+p1Name+": "+elapsedTime+" Second(s) on a ("+boardWidth+" X "+boardLength+") grid with "+mines+" Mine(s) DR: "+dec.format(difficultyRating)+"%");//writes this to file
                    bufferedWriter.newLine();
                    bufferedWriter.write(timeStamp);
                    bufferedWriter.newLine();
                    bufferedWriter.newLine();
                    bufferedWriter.close();//closes writing in file                                                 
                    System.out.println("Done");//for testing
                    avoidDoublePrint=false;//make it so that it will not print twice, as it ends the if statement
                }
            }catch (Exception e){//if an error occurs
                System.out.println("Error because of high score printing");
            }//end of catch

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("highScores.txt"));        
                     String line = br.readLine();   
                    while (line != null) {
                            for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i){
                            br.readLine();
                            if(i==3){
                                line = br.readLine();
                                double highest = Double.valueOf(line);
                                System.out.println(highest);
                                System.out.println(difficultyRating);
                                if(difficultyRating>highest){
                                    bufferedWriter.write(""+difficultyRating+"");
                                }
                            }
                          }

                        }

                    br.close();


                    } catch(Exception e){
                    }
        }//end of print high scores
```

}

Comment: please mention what you are trying to do. You want to overwrite a line at a specific position or the last written line ?

Comment: Basically, you need to read the entire file and replace the line you want and write it back out again.  Now you can get "clever" and write the content to a new file AS you read the old file, updating the line you need to update, delete the old file and rename the new file into it's place...

Comment: trojan, i am trying to overwrite in a specific position

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to overwrite a line in the file, but I don't see something, where you position the cursor or anything else.

The approach MadProgrammer mentioned in a comment under your question should be a right way:

1. Read in the file
2. Parse and modify the resulting String
3. Write back the new String

So far, so good...

**BUT** I think you'll run into problems on finding the right line to replace, because you write this to file:

```
bufferedWriter.write(""+p1Name+": "+elapsedTime+" Second(s) on a ("+boardWidth+" X "+boardLength+") grid with "+mines+" Mine(s) DR: "+dec.format(difficultyRating)+"%");
```

How do you want to determine, which line now has to be replaced?

I advise you to manage your highscores in a CSV format, so you can easily pick any value to do whatever you want to do with it:

> playername;time;boardWith;etc

Answer (score 0):

perhaps thi can help :

**sample text file :**

```
John : 1000 Second(s) on a (100X100) grid with 2 Mine(s) DR: 10.00%
06:34:23
```

(2 row)

**function :**

```
private static void ReplaceSingleLine(string path, string find, string replace)
{
    IEnumerable<string> n = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(line => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(line, find, replace));
    File.WriteAllLines(path, n);
}
```

**execution :**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string _path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
    ReplaceSingleLine(_path + "\\test.txt", "DR: .*%", "DR: 25.5%");
}
```

[use regex](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?37g55) `"DR: .*%"` to change from `DR: 10.00%` to `DR: 25.5%`